# How to generate a list of random numbers?

Tags: scala

This might be the least important Scala question ever, but it's bothering me.  How would I generate a list of n random number.  What I have so far:

```
def n_rands(n : Int) = {
 val r = new scala.util.Random
 1 to n map { _ => r.nextInt(100) } 
}
```

Which works, but doesn't look very Scalarific to me.  I'm open to suggestions.

**EDIT**

Not because it's relevant so much as it's amusing and obvious in retrospect, the following looks like it works:

```
1 to 20 map r.nextInt
```

But the index of each entry in the returned list is also the upper bound of that last.  The first number must be less than 1, the second less than 2, and so on.  I ran it three or four times and noticed "Hmmm, the result always starts with 0..."

Comment: @Jesper -- five years later and I finally do the first thing I should do...

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can either use [Don's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9094879/1730) or:

```
Seq.fill(n)(Random.nextInt)
```

Note that you don't need to create a new `Random` object, you can use the default companion object Random, as stated above.

Comment: I needed to supply a max for the `nextInt` function.  Surprisingly (to me at least) this worked: `Seq.fill(6)(Random.nextInt(100))`

Comment: It's not surprising, see the Random companion object: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Random

Comment: I meant, I was surprised that it that `Random.nextInt(100)` was interpreted as the *anonymous function* I wanted it to be and not the int-valued expressed I thought it looked like.

Comment: It's because the second parameter of the fill function is passed "by-name" (it's type is `=> E`): `Random.nextInt(100)`is evaluated for each value created.

Comment: `Seq.fill(5)(util.Random.nextInt)`

Answer (score 37):

How about:

```
import util.Random.nextInt
Stream.continually(nextInt(100)).take(10)
```

Comment: Maybe this is obvious to everyone else but I needed to do `val r = new util.Random; Stream.continually(r.nextInt).take(10)` to get the code to work.

Comment: I wrote it as `Stream.continually(r.nextInt(100)).take(10).toList` -- the `.toList` may be unnecessary but the `r.` isn't.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'd imported util.Random.nextInt as @Nicholas guessed. For a bit more utility you could make a val out of Stream.continually(nextInt(100)).

Comment: This was very useful to me because I could filter it through Stream.distinct before take(n) to get a unique sampling, which was what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

regarding your EDIT,

`nextInt` can take an `Int` argument as an upper bound for the random number, so `1 to 20 map r.nextInt` is the same as `1 to 20 map (i => r.nextInt(i))`, rather than a more useful compilation error.

`1 to 20 map (_ => r.nextInt(100))` does what you intended. But it's better to use `Seq.fill` since that more accurately represents what you're doing.