# How to generate different random number by scala? and the number should be as short as possible

Tags: scala, random

How to generate different random number by scala? and the number should be as short as possible.I want to generate unique id to label data, in the same time the id should be short enough to save the cost?

Comment: part of what you are asking can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094820/how-to-generate-a-list-of-random-numbers/9094879#9094879

Comment: thanks but sorry, it can not satisfy my requirement. I want unique random number. such as .   val r = new util.Random   println(1 to 30 map (_ => r.nextInt(100)) ). It will print:Vector(16, 20, 77, 94, 9, 82, 14, 64, 23, 44, 30, 56, 19, 75, 94, 28, 88, 78, 33, 99, 49, 62, 68, 52, 99, 21, 74, 1, 70, 75). it has the 99 repeated.

Comment: "the id should be short enough to save the cost" 
Can you elaborate more about the "cost"? You mean the cost of generating a Random number? Or cost of storing the number?

Answer (score 8):

Since your requirement is

1. random number
2. unique
3. as short as possible

Then I think you should consider to use `scala.util.Random.shuffle`, eg,

```
scala.util.Random.shuffle(1 to 30)
```

Above code will generate a `Vector` that contains unique random number (in terms of position) from 1 to 30, eg, `Vector(26, 10, 7, 29, 11, 14, 16, 1, 12, 9, 28, 6, 19, 4, 27, 8, 13, 18, 30, 20, 23, 5, 21, 24, 17, 25, 2, 15, 22, 3)`.

Basically it just fulfill everything you need.

If you prefer to get the result in `Set` or `List`, simply call `toSet` or `toList` method will do.

`nextInt` can achieve the same thing but you might need a lot of logic and *retry* mechanism for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import util.Random.nextInt
Stream.continually(nextInt(100)).take(10)
```

or you can check in console the numbers generated:

```
 import util.Random.nextInt
 val res = Stream.continually(nextInt(100)).take(10)
 res.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score -1):

So basically you can use "Set" to generate unique random numbers.

```
val r = scala.util.Random
var temp:Int = 0
var s:Set[Int] = Set()

var i:Int = 0
while(i<n){
    temp = r.nextInt(range)   //random number will be checked whether it is already in the set or not
    if(!s.contains(temp)){    //if the random number is not in the set
      s=s+temp;               //random number is added in the set
      i+=1
    }
  }
s.toArray                     //converts the set into array
```